# Subclass with additional method in Java

Tags: java, class, subclass, superclass

I have a problem with a subclass in Java. I have the following class:

```
MainIterator implements Iterator{
   //... Methods from the interface Iterator

   public void foo(){
      //Do something...
   }
}
```

and in my main class I call:

```
Iterator i = new MainIterator();
i.foo();
```

which does not work, because Iterator does not implement the function *foo()*. How is it possible to get this working without a typecast of `i`? `i` has to be from type Iterator.

Comment: well, you can do it with reflection but you should not...in this case it's just a hack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MainIterator i = new MainIterator();
```

The Java compiler only allows calling methods that belong to the *declared* type of the variable. If you use

```
Iterator i = new MainIterator();
```

you're telling the compiler: *I create an instance of Iterator which is of type MainIterator, but you don't need to know about that in the rest of the code. Just consider this object as an instance of Iterator.* And Iterator doesn't have any foo() method.

Comment: thanks for the quick response! 
However, i has to be from the type _Iterator_. Isn't there a possibility to add the methode to the type _Iterator_?

Comment: A MainIterator **is a** Iterator. You can pass an instance of MainIterator to any method that needs an Iterator. That's the whole point of polymorphism. Let's say someone asks you a phone to pass a phone call. You can give him your smart phone, because a smart phone is a phone. But if you have a phone you can't surf the web unless the phone is actually a smart phone. So, if you want to phone, declaring your smart phone as a phone is sufficient. If you want to surf the web, you'll have to tell the compiler that you have a smart phone, and not just a phone.

Comment: I understand your example. This is kind a weird task which i had to do for school. I do not necessarily have to define a new class _MainIterator_, however i have to get `((Iterator) i).foo()` to work, but i see no other way than creating a subclass...

Comment: ((Iterator) i).foo() will never work, since Iterator doesn't have a foo method. Ask another question explaining whatyou're trying to achieve, at a higher level, and with more of the relevant code.

Comment: ok, i see the only way is to define _i_ as _MainIterator_ instead of _Iterator_.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your variable as `MainIterator`:

```
MainIterator i = new MainIterator();
i.foo();
```

Or you can cast:

```
Iterator i = new MainIterator();
((MainIterator) i).foo();
```

There are no other ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Iterator does not define foo() so you can not directly call foo() on a variable of type Iterator.

MainIterator defines foo() so you can call foo() on a variable of type MainIterator or a subtype.

You can cast a variable of type Iterator to MainIterator. There is really no other way around this. That is how it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are *sure* at the point where you are using `i`, that `i` is *definitely* of type `MainIterator`, it is alright to cast it. Also, if you are sure that you need a concrete *MainIterator* instance at this point, then you can simply type it as `MainIterator i = new MainIterator()`. For both cases it means that your design is tightly coupled to a particular implementation, which defeats the purpose of using an interface. So at this point I'd take a look at the design to make sure that happens where you are *sure* that all you need is an instance of `MainIterator` and no other instance.

If you *must* use `Iterator` but `i` can be any implementation of `Iterator`, you have a design problem because you are tightly coupled to a particular implementation (because you *want* to use the `void foo` method), but your code *also* wants to work with all implementations. This is a contradiction that you have to resolve, and it is hard to say how you can rectify it without looking at your overall design.